# How to open correctly a vertex and fragment shaders on QT Creator

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, qt-creator

So I am trying to open my texture.fs and texture.vs on Qt creator and I am still having an error. In order to open the different files I used the Qt Creator functions, it's easier for that. So the following code is (this code is in the FragmentGeometry.cpp file) :

```
    void FrameGeometry::initShaders()
{
    program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();

    // Compile vertex shader
    if (!program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/Other\files/texture.vs"))
        std::cout<<"Problem while adding vertex shader"<<std::endl;

    // Compile fragment shader
    if (!program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "texture.fs"))
        std::cout<<"Problem while adding fragment shader"<<std::endl;

    // Link shader pipeline
    if (!program->link())
        std::cout<<"Problem while linking program"<<std::endl;
}
```

And the error is : 
[image: error picture]

I tried lot of different paths too and I still don't know why it's not working. The hierarchy of my code is : 
[image: hierarchy code]

Can you help me to understand why it's not working please ?

Comment: The relative path is relative to the binary executable instead of the source file location. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: @Maverobot I am using a Mac with Qt creator and the executable seems Xcode for it. I put the shader in my principal file, but we you had this shaders to the project on Qt Creator, it considers this file as 'other files' so I thought the right path was '":/Other\files/texture.vs" ' but it still not working and I don't know why. I tried many other ways like ' "/Other files/texture.vs" or "/Other\files/texture.vs" or "../Other\files/texture.vs".

Comment: Can you please try with absolute path?

Comment: I tried but the files still unable to open @Maverobot

Comment: You might be missing one whitespace in the path - `../Other\ files/texture.vs`. Also try to name the folders without whitespaces.

Comment: General tips:  1 - Qt Creator is just the IDE.  Talking about "Qt Creator Functions" makes no sense.  2- The error is about not opening the file, so it has nothing to do with vertex shaders.  When debugging this kind of issue, just try to make a QFile that opens the path and you can bypass the complexity of shaders and whatnot.  Start by understanding the path where things are.

Answer (score 1):

The colon (`:`) suggests your files should be declared in a .qrc file - that is, a [Qt Resources file](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html). If you are using Qt Creator, you need to add the line `RESOURCES = your_resources_file.qrc` to `test_build_project_new.pro`. Then, make sure `your_resources_file.qrc` declares the files you need. This could be an example:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>shaders/texture.vs</file>
    <file>shaders/texture.fs</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then, from your code you'd open the files like this:

```cpp
void FrameGeometry::initShaders()
{
    program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();

    // Compile vertex shader
    if (!program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/shaders/texture.vs"))
        std::cout<<"Problem while adding vertex shader"<<std::endl;

    // Compile fragment shader
    if (!program->addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/shaders/texture.fs"))
        std::cout<<"Problem while adding fragment shader"<<std::endl;

    // Link shader pipeline
    if (!program->link())
        std::cout<<"Problem while linking program"<<std::endl;
}
```

Just make sure you place the shaders in the correct directory. In this example, this would be in `$YOUR_PROJECT_ROOT/shaders/`.
Also, make sure your shaders are not declared in `DISTFILES` in your .pro file (I see your shaders are currently under the Other Files category). If you use Qt Resources you don't need to declare them as `DISTFILES` as well.